# Need to return a comma separated value based on two separate data points

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv

I have data in a table that looks like this (we'll call it PersonServiceArea for this exercise):

> PersonKey ServiceAreaState    ServiceAreaCounties
>
> 30076 DC  * *<- Since no counties exist here, this is how we treat the
>   County field*
>
> 30076 VA  ARLINGTON
>
> 30076 VA  BEDFORD
>
> 30076 VA  ETC
>
> 12345 PA  BUCKS
>
> 12345 PA  CHESTER
>
> 12345 PA  MONTGOMERY

What I need to do is write something that pulls it together in this format:

> PersonKey ServiceAreaState    ServiceAreaCounties
>
> 30076 DC  *
>
> 30076 VA  ARLINGTON,BEDFORD,ETC
>
> 12345 PA  BUCKS,CHESTER,MONTGOMERY

However, all I keep coming up with is:

> PersonKey ServiceAreaState    ServiceAreaCounties
>
> 30076 DC  *
>
> 30076 DC  ALEXANDRIA,CITY,ARLINGTON,BEDFORD
>
> 30076 DC  ALLEGANY,ANNE,ARUNDEL,BALTIMORE
>
> 30076 DC  BERKELEY,JEFFERSON,MORGAN
>
> 30076 DC  BRUNSWICK,DUPLIN,NEW,HANOVER

As you can see, my issue is setting up my query so that, for each PersonKey and each individual ServiceAreaState they work in, I only get results back FOR THAT STATE, and not a repeating mess of every county they service under every state they service. Also, counties that consist of two words end up with a comma delimiter as well--how can I avoid this?

For the record, working on this in SQL Server 2008. Any and all help to avoid setting up 100 temporary tables to do the job on a state-by-state basis would be much appreciated!

Comment: What's your query look like now? It sounds like some creative grouping may need to occur.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is "group_concat" (which is available in mysql but not sql server) Nevertheless, take a look at [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using `recursive cte`

```
select 30076 PersonKey, 'DC' ServiceAreaState, '*' ServiceAreaCounties
into #a
union
select 30076 PersonKey, 'VA' ServiceAreaState, 'ARLINGTON' ServiceAreaCounties
union 
select 30076 PersonKey, 'VA' ServiceAreaState, 'BEDFORD' ServiceAreaCounties
union
select 30076 PersonKey, 'VA' ServiceAreaState, 'ETC' ServiceAreaCounties
union
select 12345 PersonKey, 'PA' ServiceAreaState, 'BUCKS' ServiceAreaCounties
union
select 12345 PersonKey, 'PA' ServiceAreaState, 'CHESTER' ServiceAreaCounties
union 
select 12345 PersonKey, 'PA' ServiceAreaState, 'MONTGOMERY' ServiceAreaCounties


;with cte as
(
select PersonKey, ServiceAreaState, cast(ServiceAreaCounties as varchar(100)) ServiceAreaCounties, rown from (select PersonKey, ServiceAreaState, ServiceAreaCounties, row_number() over (partition by cast(PersonKey as varchar(10))+ ServiceAreaState  order by (select null))rown from #a)A where rown = 1
union all
select A.PersonKey, A.ServiceAreaState, cast((A.ServiceAreaCounties + ' '+ cte.ServiceAreaCounties) as varchar(100)) ServiceAreaCounties, A.rown from (select PersonKey, ServiceAreaState, ServiceAreaCounties, row_number() over (partition by cast(PersonKey as varchar(10)) + ServiceAreaState  order by (select null))rown from #a)A JOIN CTE on cte.rown + 1 = A.rown and cte.PersonKey = A.PersonKey and cte.ServiceAreaState = A.ServiceAreaState
)

select PersonKey, ServiceAreaState, ServiceAreaCounties ServiceAreaCountiesConcatenated from (
select PersonKey, ServiceAreaState, ServiceAreaCounties, rown, row_number() over (partition by cast(PersonKey as varchar(10)) + ServiceAreaState order by rown desc)newrown from cte)A where newrown = 1
```

**RESULTS**

[image]